# Code Highlighting in tikzposter

Tags: tikz-pgf, highlighting

I am doing a poster and I would like to show some programming code.

With the package `\begin{minted}{python}`.....`\end{minted}` there is a beautiful code highlighting but it doesn't work in tikzposter. How could I highlight the code?

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\title{Mandelbrotmengen und Juliamengen}
\author{Fachschaften Mathematik und Informatik}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{minted}
\usetheme{Board}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{Mandelbrotmengen}
{
    Die \textbf{Mandelbrotmenge}, benannt nach Benoit Mandelbrot, ist die Menge der komplexen Zahlen $c$, für welche die durch die iterative Vorschrift $z_{n+1} = z_{n}^2+c$ mit dem Anfangswert $z_0 = 0$ definierte Folge $z_0, z_1, z_2, z_3,...$ endlich bleibt, d.h. beschränkt ist.


    Interpretiert man die Mandelbrot-Menge (eine Teilmenge der Gaußschen Zahlenebenen) als geometrische Figur, so ergibt sie ein Fraktal, das im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch oft Apfelmännchen genannt wird. Bilder berechnet man, indem man jedem Pixel $(x,y)$ eines Bildes eine komplexe Zahl zuordnet und beginnend mit $z_0 =0$ untersucht, ob und wann die Iterationen anfangen, zu „explodieren“. Bleiben die Werte klein, wird das Pixel häufig schwarz gefärbt, kommt es zu einer „Explosion“ der Zahlenwerte, wird die Anzahl der dafür notwendigen Iterationen als Farbe kodiert.

            \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{pics/madelbrot.png}
        \end{tikzfigure}

    Die ersten mit einem Computer generierten Darstellungen wurden 1978 von Robert W. Brooks und Peter Matelski vorgestellt. 1980 veröffentlichte Benoît Mandelbrot eine Arbeit über das Thema. Später wurde sie von Adrien Douady und John Hamal Hubbard in einer Reihe grundlegender mathematischer Arbeiten systematisch untersucht. Die mathematischen Grundlagen dafür wurden bereits 1905 von dem französischen Mathematiker Pierre Fatou erarbeitet.


 


    
}


\block{Juliamengen}
{
    Die \textbf{Julia-Mengen}, erstmals von Gaston Maurice Julia und Pierre Fatou beschrieben, sind Teilmengen der komplexen Zahlenebene, wobei zu jeder holomorphen oder meromorphen Funktion eine Julia-Menge gehört. Oft sind die Julia-Mengen fraktale Mengen. Das Komplement der Julia-Menge heißt Fatou-Menge.\\
    Wendet man eine auf ganz $\mathbb{C}$ definierte Funktion $f$ immer wieder auf ihre Funktionswerte an, dann ergibt sich für jedes $z$ eine Folge komplexer Zahlen:

    \begin{center}
        

       $ z  \mapsto f(z)    \mapsto f(f(z))     \mapsto ...$
    \end{center}


        \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, auto=left]{pics/Julia-Set_z2+c_-1_0.png}
            %\caption{Julia - Menge für $z \mapsto z^2-1$}
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, auto=right]{pics/Julia-Set_z2+c_-0.6_0.6.png}
            %\caption{Julia - Menge für $z \mapsto z^2 -0.6 + 0.6i$}
        \end{tikzfigure}




    Die ersten mit einem Computer generierten Darstellungen wurden 1978 von Robert W. Brooks und Peter Matelski vorgestellt. 1980 veröffentlichte Benoît Mandelbrot eine Arbeit über das Thema. Später wurde sie von Adrien Douady und John Hamal Hubbard in einer Reihe grundlegender mathematischer Arbeiten systematisch untersucht. Die mathematischen Grundlagen dafür wurden bereits 1905 von dem französischen Mathematiker Pierre Fatou erarbeitet.
 


    
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile, mostly because you include `jpg` images that are not included. Moreover, your sample code does not include any `minted` environment, so it is unclear what exactly your problem is and what you want to achieve. Please replace the code by a complete example, and make sure that it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I have used a number of times is to create a "stand alone" latex document (using the standalone calss) and there to produce a code listing with minted. Then you can include the PDF using `includegraphics` as always into your document. This has the advantage that for many minted code snippets, the compilation becomes slow. Including PDFs does not (really) slow down the compilation of your document. Last but not least, `minted` is not installed on each computer (or conference submission system, published, ...).